Resetting brocade vdx 6720 password to default without boot password
I want to reset a Brocade VDX 6720-24 switch that i got from ebay to default settings. It has a boot password. Extreme networks can not help with the recovery string because it is past end of life. Is there another way? Can I reset through the motherboard and how?

Have you tried Extreme community support? https://community.extremenetworks.com/t5/data-center-vdx/bd-p/Data_Center_VDX

Yes, posted there a week ago, no response. https://community.extremenetworks.com/t5/data-center-vdx/bootprom-password-recovery/td-p/100647
